# How do I add "args=(...)" into arguments of my own function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, arguments, numerical-methods

in scipy there is a function `quad()`:

```
quad(integrand, 0, 1, args=(a,b))
```

I have my own function to take integrals using gauss legendgre quadrature, and when I integrate different functions with parameters im kinda tired of adding them. So the question is:

is there a way to add an argument `args=(...)` into arguments of my own function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure,

```
def my_function(value1, value2, value3, args=(0,0)):
    print(value1, value2, value3, args)

# call with only 3 values
# it will use args=(0,0) as default
my_function(1,2,3)

# call with 3 values and args
my_function(4,5,6, args=(7,8))
```

output:

```
1 2 3 (0, 0)
4 5 6 (7, 8)
```